# Getting null while passing data through a bundle from Activity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

Losing data on the way when passing it through bundle, i get

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference at *String bundlePassData = this.getArguments().getString("tagName");*

Here it's a sample of my code. MainActivity->

```
 tagsView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagName);
            String selectedItemName = textView.getText().toString();
            bundle.putString("tagName", selectedItemName);

            TaskAssignFragment taskAssignFragment = new TaskAssignFragment();
            taskAssignFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new TaskAssignFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            Log.i("ListView", selectedItemName);
        }
    });
```

TaskAssignFragment->

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_assign, container, false);
    TextView test = view.findViewById(R.id.testerView);

    String bundlePassData = this.getArguments().getString("tagName");
    test.setText(bundlePassData);

    return view;
}
```

Should I try `interfaces`? But if i would i need the data as a variable, not in only a function, because i would use it in more places in my `fragment`.

Comment: maybe your original getter returned null

Comment: I tested it in the Log.i("ListView", selectedItemName); , it returns just the string I want, that's not the problem

Comment: how is that related to your this.getArguments() ? that is what I'm talking about

Comment: You have never used your created-with-arguments fragment `taskAssignFragment`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad.. Fixed it, much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code You are creating new fragment when replacing.

```
TaskAssignFragment taskAssignFragment = new TaskAssignFragment();
            taskAssignFragment.setArguments(bundle);

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new TaskAssignFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

use the fragment instance you already created in which you set arguments

```
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                   taskAssignFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call method directly on fragment e.g:

```
TaskAssignFragment taskAssignFragment = new TaskAssignFragment();
// Call here your own method (from fragment)
taskAssignFragment.setSelectedItemName(selectedItemName);
```

And in your fragment:

```
public void setSelectedItemName(String selectedItemName) {
    // Store data as field in class
    this.selectedName = selectedItemName
}
```

where `selectedName` is field in your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
tagsView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tagName);
            String selectedItemName = textView.getText().toString();
            bundle.putString("tagName", selectedItemName);

            TaskAssignFragment taskAssignFragment = new TaskAssignFragment();
            taskAssignFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    taskAssignFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            Log.i("ListView", selectedItemName);
        }
    });
```

Please try this code, you create a new instance of TaskAssignFragment() and pass it without arguments

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new object while replacing fragment.

```
        TaskAssignFragment taskAssignFragment = new TaskAssignFragment();
        taskAssignFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                taskAssignFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Try this out